# Яке походження фразеологізму "посипати голову попелом"?

Tags: етимологія, фразеологізми

Сьогодні почула цікавий фразеологізм: посипати голову попелом. Одразу полізла у словник. У [Словопедії](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53407/360350.html) читаю:

> **посипа́ти (присипа́ти) / поси́пати (приси́пати) го́лову по́пелом**, книжн. Вдаватися в тугу, в розпач, втрачати мужність, надію; картати себе, журитися і т. ін. Надягнувши траур і волосяниці, посипа́ли голову попелом бідні батьки і голосно кричали (П. Загребельний); Нині, стоячи на руїні з жебрацькою торбою, посипаємо голову попелом, волаючи: нас обдурили — плану перебудови не було! Та в тому ж і сіль, що був він! Тільки не той (Б. Олійник); — Ну, друзі? — кинув бадьоро вусами (Жук). — Не казав я вам, що немає чого попелом голови присипати?.. Не говорив, що справа не загине на Затишній? (П. Козланюк).

Цікавить те, звідки такий фразеологізм взявся? Що ж могло передувати його виникненню (етимологія)? У Словопедії, на жаль, немає.

Comment: У католицькій церкві великодній піст щороку розпочинається у попільну середу з посипання голів попелом, під час цього образу священик промовляє: "з попелу вийшов - в попіл обернешся".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**"Посипати голову попелом"**](http://myhelper.com.ua/index.php?newsid=25919) означає бути в сильному відчаї, сумувати.
У [Біблії](http://faqukrn.ru/osvita/serednja-osvita-i-shkoli/6381-posipati-golovu-popelom-znachennja-frazeologizmu.html) ми дізнаємося про незвичайну традицію євреїв, яку вони здійснювали при смерті або іншому великому нещастю своїх близьких, а також при власних бідах. У такі моменти вони сипали на свою голову попіл або ж землю. Такий ритуал показував їх скорботу і відчай. Він був знаковим і містив у собі глибокий зміст. Детальнішу інформацію можна занайти [тут](http://arhistratig.in.ua/2014/06/18/posipati-golovu-popelom/).

Звичай посипати голову попелом зберігся тільки в деяких народів Сходу і Півдня. У нашій культурі звичай залишив слід лише у мові. Ми до цього дня говоримо "посипати голову попелом", коли хочемо показати сильну скорбота і горе.

Comment: дякую допомогли дуже дуже сильно